# C# Method Overload Problem With Class Derived From Generic Abstract Class

Tags: c#, overloading, generics

I am working on a project, and I have a generic abstract type that takes a type parameter that is itself derived from the abstract type.  If you want to know why I would do this, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330841/abstract-generic-classes-taking-type-parameters-that-are-themselves-derived-from).

I have run into an interesting problem with overloading a method in a derived class that is defined in the abstract class.  Here is a code sample:

```
public abstract class AbstractConverter<T, U>
    where U : AbstractConvertible
    where T : AbstractConverter<T, U>
{
    public abstract T Convert(U convertible);
}

public class DerivedConvertibleConverter : AbstractConverter<DerivedConvertibleConverter, DerivedConvertible>
{
    public DerivedConvertibleConverter(DerivedConvertible convertible)
    {
        Convert(convertible);
    }

    public override DerivedConvertibleConverter Convert(DerivedConvertible convertible)
    {
        //This will not be called
        System.Console.WriteLine("Called the most derived method");
        return this;
    }

    public DerivedConvertibleConverter Convert(Convertible convertible)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Called the least derived method");
        return this;
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractConvertible {}

public class Convertible : AbstractConvertible {}

public class DerivedConvertible : Convertible {}
```

In the sample above, the overload of Convert that does not exist in the abstract parent (and is less derived) is called.  I would expect that the most derived version, from the parent class, would be called.

In trying to troubleshoot this problem, I ran into an interesting solution:

```
public abstract class AbstractConverter<U>
    where U : AbstractConvertible
{
    public abstract AbstractConverter<U> Convert(U convertible);
}

public class DerivedConvertibleConverter : AbstractConverter<DerivedConvertible>
{
    public DerivedConvertibleConverter(DerivedConvertible convertible)
    {
        Convert(convertible);
    }

    public override DerivedConvertibleConverter Convert(DerivedConvertible convertible)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Called the most derived method");
        return this;
    }

    public DerivedConvertibleConverter Convert(Convertible convertible)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Called the least derived method");
        return this;
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractConvertible {}

public class Convertible : AbstractConvertible {}

public class DerivedConvertible : Convertible {}
```

When the derived type argument is removed from the base class, the most derived version of Convert is called.  I would not expect this difference, since I would not have expected the interface of the abstract version of Convert to have changed.  However, I must be wrong.  Can anyone explain why this difference occurs?  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your second code snippet shouldn't compile btw, as the Convert method is not covariant. (i.e., it is expected to return an `AbstractConverter<DerivedConvertible>`, and not the more derived `DerivedConvertibleConverted`)

Comment: Thank you, Mark.  You are correct.  However, before compilation, the IDE will resolve the correct version of the method in that state.  If I fix the method to have the correct return type of `AbstractConverter<DerivedConvertible>`, the same problem arises, resulting in the less-derived method being called.  Perhaps there is no work-around to this problem.

Comment: There's a simple workaround, that is to say (in the first snippet for example) `(this as AbstractConverter<DerivedConvertibleConverter, DerivedConvertible>).Convert(convertible));` inside the .ctor. The main problem is that both Convert methods are matched by the call. I'm unsure of the criteria the compiler uses for best match, but it seems the second method is a better match because DerivedConvertible does not directly inherit from AbstractConvertible. It's only direct base class is Convertible, which is matched exactly by the second method.

Comment: When the code is incorrect, the IDE is making the best guess it can given an erroneous program. You can't make any deductions about what is *legal* from the IDE's guesses when you give it an illegal program.  It's error recovery heuristics do not look into the future to see how you are going to resolve the error!

Comment: In this particular case, the IDE is probably guessing that the "override" is the error, and assuming that you will remove it, since the method does not actually override anything; it cannot, since the return type does not match. If the IDE assumes that it is not an override then overload resolution might choose it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In the sample above, the overload of Convert that does not exist in the abstract parent (and is less derived) is called. I would expect that the most derived version, from the parent class, would be called

Many people have this expectation. However, the behaviour you are observing is correct and by design.

The overload resolution algorithm goes like this. First we make a list of all the possible accessible methods you could be calling. **Methods which override virtual methods are considered to be methods of the class which declared them, not the class which overrode them.** Then we filter out the ones where the arguments cannot be converted to the formal parameter types. Then we filter out all the methods that are on any type *less derived* than any type that had an applicable method. Then we determine which method is better than another, if there is still more than one method left.

In your case there are two possible applicable methods. The one that takes a DerivedConvertible is considered to be a method of the base class, and is therefore not as good as the one that takes a Convertible.

The principle here is that **overriding a virtual method is an implementation detail subject to change, and not a hint to the compiler that the overriding method is to be chosen.**

More generally, these features of the overload resolution algorithm are designed to help mitigate various versions of the Brittle Base Class problem.

For more details about these design decisions see my article on the subject:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/future-breaking-changes-part-three

> When the derived type argument is removed from the base class, the most derived version of Convert is called. I would not expect this difference, since I would not have expected the interface of the abstract version of Convert to have changed

The question is based on a false premise; the most derived version is *not* called. The program fragment is erroneous, and therefore does not compile, and therefore neither method is called; the program doesn't run because it does not compile.